# Avoid PUT response data to contain full data with nested serializer and generic views (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API based on a [RetrieveUpdateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview) with a [Writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers). The issue I have is that when I make a PUT request, the response data contains all the data of the serializer... And the amount of those data is pretty big.

**How can I modify my code to avoid this behavior? I imagine that this should be at the level of the view?** I would preferably stick to generic views.

Thanks for your support.

For the record,

Here is the serializer code:

```
# DatetimeValue serializer
class DatetimeValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DatetimeValue
        fields = ['date_time', 'value']


# Serializer that includes time series header and date time values
class TimeSeriesValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    values = DatetimeValueSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TimeSeries
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'values']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ts_name = validated_data.pop('name')

        try:
            time_series = TimeSeries.objects.get(name=ts_name)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(_(f"Time series doesn't exist"))

        values_data = validated_data.pop('values')
        for datetime_value in values_data:
            try:
                DatetimeValue.objects.create(time_series=time_series, **datetime_value)
            except IntegrityError:
                raise ValidationError(_(f"ERROR in 'date_time' and/or 'value' provided. "
                                        f"'date_time' has to be a correct date time format and 'value' a float. "
                                        f"A 'date_time' has to be unique for a given time series"))
        return time_series
```

And the view code:

```
# View to get time series datetime values
class TimeSeriesValueDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = TimeSeries.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeSeriesValueSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `serialzier_class` depending on `request.method` using `get_serializer_class`

```
class TimeSeriesValueDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = TimeSeries.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeSeriesValueSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            return ShortTimeSeriesSerializer
        return super().get_serializer_class()
```

or you can return a custom data at the end of the `put` handler:

```
class TimeSeriesValueDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)        
        return Response(data={'success':True})
```

or you can return some other data after the update:

```
class TimeSeriesValueDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    ...
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(data={'success':True})
```

Comment: Thanks for your efficient and quick response. I implemented the second way and it works fine. However, I imagine that the first one would be more efficient in term of performance as it will avoid to build the *complete set of data* in the serializer. Do you confirm that it makes sense? But then I have to implement this other serializer **ShortTimeSeriesSerializer**?

Comment: That is correct. You can always override the whole `update` function instead of calling the parent's `update`. You can see how that function works in https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L63. Just copy the whole update function except for the `return Response(serializer.data)`

Comment: You should probably also change the `partial_update` method for `PATCH` requests.